# How to get image from url to imageView to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I wan't to assign Image to `ImageView` from url, which I got from `JSON`. I want to store fetched data in `RecyclerView`.

I've tried a lot of methods that users were proposed such as:

```
Picasso.with(recyclerItem.getContext()).load(news.getUrlImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

,

```
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(news.getUrlImage()).getContent());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

with and without `AsyncTask` and no one from the above-mentioned method doesn't work.

overwritten `onBindViewHolder` method from NewsAdapter.java (that extend `RecyclerView.Adapter` class):

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: START");
    News news = newsList.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(news.getTitle());
    holder.author.setText(news.getAuthor());
    holder.publishedDate.setText(news.getPublishedAt());

    Picasso.with(recyclerItem.getContext()).load(news.getUrlImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

`TextView` are assigned properly and work well, only `ImageView` is making troubles.

Does anybody has idea how make that it would work properly?

Comment: Picasso *should* work, so what does "making troubles" mean?

Comment: Picasso is good, but I doubt your "news.getUrlImage()". Print this and check it in Web that it is displaying image or not

Comment: It's unbelievable but I didn't change anything and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image loading library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images into your `ImageView`. They both have a similar API.

An example:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String imgUrl = mData.get(position).getImageUrl;
    //Picasso
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(imgUrl).into(holder.mImageView);
    //Glide
    Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl).into(holder.mImageView);
}
```